# Golang. Viper не определяет файл конфигурации config

Tags: golang

После успешной установки viper в свой модуль, создания файла конфигурации и функции, которая читает значение ключа из данного файла и передает это значение как параметр методу Run, при запуске кода объявляется следующая проблема:

2022/01/06 22:31:50 error initializing configs: Unsupported Config Type ""
exit status 1

Пробовал следующее:

1.Переименовывать репозиторий с config файлом, заполнять его большим количеством пар ключ-значение

2.Прописывать формат файла .yaml/yml; искать по формату через AddConfigPath("yaml") вместо viper.SetConfigFile("config")

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, в чем может быть проблема. Делаю все по туториалу точь-в-точь. Если не прописывать файл-конфигурацию не прибегать к viper, а указывать в методе Run параметры напрямую, то все работает и сервер запускается. Но надо же разобраться и понять, что я делаю не так.

[image: Мой код main.go, где видно расположение файлов]
[image: Содержимое файла конфигурации.]

Comment: @Senior Pomidor да, я пробовал , как port: 8000,  port: "8000" и port: ":8000", так и абсурдное port 8000 без разделителя) Нет результата. Просто воспринимается пустой строкой файл. Хз, почему.

Answer (score 1):

не хватает еще пару шагов для viper-а. но также не забудьте добавить хотя бы расширение `yaml` к файлу `config`

```
v := viper.New()
v.SetConfigName("config")
v.SetConfigType("yaml")
v.AddConfigPath(".")
v.AddConfigPath("./configs")

var cfg Config
if err := v.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
    return errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to read config")
}
```

`v.AddConfigPath("./configs")` - это понятно. оно нужно, чтобы найти в директории конфиг. Но когда вы скомпилириуете в бинарь, и чтобы вам не создавать директорию конфиг, можно еще добавить `v.AddConfigPath(".")`, чтобы искал в текушей директории.

p.s. рекомендую помотреть на [aconfig](https://github.com/cristalhq/aconfig)

Comment: Я забил на эту проблему, просто перекинув файл конфигурации в директорию к главному файлу. Так он его видит без проблем. Но теперь вновь столкнулся и, уже дня 2, бьюсь, но ничего не могу поделать : он просто НЕ ХОЧЕТ ВИДЕТЬ ЭТОТ ФАЙЛ, если он находится в другой директории.

Comment: + крайне сильно подбешивает то, что ВО ВСЕХ туториалах, авторы просто указывают путь и у них все работает

Comment: так я же вам описал про AddConfigPath

Comment: @ Senior Pomidor благодарю за советы) Но файл действительно читает только лишь из главной директории с файлом main, который к нему и обращается. Ни из общей, ни из отд. директории для config'ов- никак. Даже при указании абсолютного пути и остальных параметров - все тщетно. Либо он лежит в папке с главным файлом- либо его не читает. В доках об этом ни слова не сказано. Тут пытались найти решение но, как я понял- к общему не пришли. https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/390